Is it correct to study machine learning? Question based on knowledge of unseen related to my studies
Is it correct to study machine learning?
If a match is played by the teams and based on data in my subject, it shows 58% team A will win, is this haram?

machine learning give output of unseen data according to subject


the subject contains statements "will wiN"


Certainly yes, no problem with it!
Scientifically, or based on any sort of experiences, forecasting the future is not Haram, as long as you know "وَ قَالَتِ الْيَهُودُ يَدُ اللَّهِ مَغْلُولَةٌ غُلَّتْ أَيْدِيهِمْ وَ لُعِنُوا بِمَا قَالُوا بَلْ يَدَاهُ مَبْسُوطَتَانِ" which is translated into "The Jews say: Allah's hand is tied up. Be their hands tied up and be they accursed for the (blasphemy) they utter. Nay, both His hands are widely outstretched".
Also using probability in forecasting automatically rule out the statement from being Kufr or things like that, since you are admitting I guess but am not sure what will happen in future, admitting not being aware of what will really happen, and that my guess is just a rather wise one.
This is why we can live with other people in a society, trying to understand each other although only Allah knows how we ourselves really are. This is why we can estimate tomorrow's whether, or design an engineering plan and estimate how it will work based on computer simulation, or previous experiments. And so many alike examples ...
